# Prevent Music app from downloading artist images

Tags: ios, music

The artist view in the iOS7 Music app on my iPad uses images that are not in the song files, nor occur anywhere in iTunes on the Mac. So it must have downloaded them from Apple, using the artist name. This is error-prone and a privacy issue. How can I disable it?

I do not have an iCloud account (Apple ID doesn't contain @) and never used iTunes Match.